# open a pyqt5 window from another window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

This is only my 1st day with pyqt5. I want to open the main app window after login is successful.

This is the code below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'void.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


import pysftp, datetime as dt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QCheckBox, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QPixmap, QIcon


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(711, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 90, 47, 14))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 711, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hey "))


class LoginForm(QWidget, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('SFTP Client v1.0 - Login')
        self.resize(400, 50)

        icon = QIcon("./img/icon1.ico")
        QWidget.setWindowIcon(self, icon)
        layout = QGridLayout()

        label_name = QLabel('<font size="4"> Username: </font>')
        self.lineEdit_username = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_username.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your username')
        layout.addWidget(label_name, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_username, 0, 1)

        label_password = QLabel('<font size="4"> Password: </font>')
        self.lineEdit_password = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_password.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your password')
        layout.addWidget(label_password, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_password, 1, 1)

        button_login = QPushButton('Login')
        # self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        button_login.clicked.connect(self.check_password)
        layout.addWidget(button_login, 1, 0, 2, 10)
        layout.setRowMinimumHeight(2, 75)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def open_app(self):
        print('trying to open')

        self.MainWindow = self.QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = self.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.show()

    def check_password(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        login_result = self.lineEdit_username.text() == 'admin' and self.lineEdit_password.text() == '0000'
        if login_result:

            icon = QPixmap("./img/icon1.ico")
            msg.setIconPixmap(icon)
            msg.setText('Login successful! \n\nPress OK to open the SFTP Client')
            msg.setWindowTitle('SFTP Client Login')
            msg.exec_()
            # print('opening')
            self.open_app()
            # app.quit()

        else:
            icon = QPixmap("./img/icon1.ico")
            msg.setIconPixmap(icon)
            msg.setWindowTitle('SFTP Client Login')
            msg.setText('Incorrect username/password! \n\nPlease enter the correct username and password')
            msg.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    login = LoginForm()
    login.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have created a method in the login class that is supposed to be called when login in successful. the method is indeed called because of the print that I see. but does not open the other window.

Comment: Typo: remove `self` from `self.QtWidgets.QMainWindow()` and `self.Ui_MainWindow()`. You should also remove the `Ui_MainWindow` inheritance from `LoginForm` because you're not using it. I suggest you to do some more research about classes, instances, inheritance, object attributes and OOP in general. Also please note that editing pyuic files is considered bad practice and always discouraged (see that "Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing."). Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: That worked thanks. that was not the correct way to call a class instance. I'm very new to OOP as well.

Comment: My next question would be, how do I adjust the size of the login button?

Comment: Sorry but comments should always be inherent to the subject of the question. Please check more carefully the [tour] (remember that this is not a forum) and [ask]. Also, take your time to patiently study the *whole* documentation about [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html), which is the base class upon *any* widget in Qt is built, including QPushButtons.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a `QMainWindow` to `Ui_MainWindow`, you should subclass it. All references to `MainWindow` should then become references to `self`. You also don't need to `setObjectName`. You could also show the main window first, then show a dialog to get the login details (tutorial: https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt-dialogs/).

```
import pysftp
import datetime as dt

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QStatusBar, QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon


class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.resize(711, 600)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(250, 90, 47, 14))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
        
        self.menubar = QMenuBar()
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 711, 22))
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)


class LoginForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('SFTP Client v1.0 - Login')
        self.resize(400, 50)

        icon = QIcon("./img/icon1.ico")
        QWidget.setWindowIcon(self, icon)
        layout = QGridLayout()

        label_name = QLabel('<font size="4"> Username: </font>')
        self.lineEdit_username = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_username.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your username')
        layout.addWidget(label_name, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_username, 0, 1)

        label_password = QLabel('<font size="4"> Password: </font>')
        self.lineEdit_password = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_password.setPlaceholderText('Please enter your password')
        layout.addWidget(label_password, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_password, 1, 1)

        button_login = QPushButton('Login')
        # self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        button_login.clicked.connect(self.check_password)
        layout.addWidget(button_login, 1, 0, 2, 10)
        layout.setRowMinimumHeight(2, 75)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def open_app(self):
        print('trying to open')

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.close()
        self.ui.show()

    def check_password(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        login_result = self.lineEdit_username.text() == 'admin' and self.lineEdit_password.text() == '0000'
        if login_result:

            icon = QPixmap("./img/icon1.ico")
            msg.setIconPixmap(icon)
            msg.setText('Login successful! \n\nPress OK to open the SFTP Client')
            msg.setWindowTitle('SFTP Client Login')
            msg.exec_()
            # print('opening')
            self.open_app()
            # app.quit()

        else:
            icon = QPixmap("./img/icon1.ico")
            msg.setIconPixmap(icon)
            msg.setWindowTitle('SFTP Client Login')
            msg.setText('Incorrect username/password! \n\nPlease enter the correct username and password')
            msg.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = LoginForm()
    login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```